# How to android receives authToken

Tags: android, android-source, auth-token

Where to find the source code for getting AuthToken.
In the folder with the android source (core/java/android/accounts), I found the code only works stored in a database and extracts from it.
But I am interested in the code that makes a request to the server for AuthToken
I'm wondering which of the four methods (OAuth 1.0, AuthSub, ClientLogin and OAuth 2.0) use, because OAuth 1.0, AuthSub, and ClientLogin have been deprecated.

Comment: If three of them are deprecated why do not use the forth one?